# Android OPEN_DOCUMENT activities failing on OnePlus 8T (KB2005)

Tags: root-access, files, oneplus-one, intents

I have OnePlus 8T (KB2005), OxygenOS 13.1.0.581 (KB2005_13.1.0.581 (EX01)). Rooted with Magisk (26300), Zygisk enabled.

When an app attempts to bring up a file opening dialogue, it either crashes or fails for some reason. For instance, I can't attach files in the Gmail app or open a ROM in My Boy!, and this issue seems to occur with all apps.

The problem appears to be related to handling [`ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE) and also `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`.

Here's an example of the exact error taken from logcat:

```
notifyUnstableAppInfo: Bundle[{unstableTime=1697596562427, reason=crash, userId=0, exceptionMsg=No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.OPEN_DOCUMENT cat=[android.intent.category.OPENABLE] typ=*/* (has extras) }, exceptionClass=android.content.ActivityNotFoundException, app_channel_type=unstable, packageName=com.fastemulator.gba, unstable_restrict_switch=true}]
```

This seems to suggest that none of the apps I have support this particular activity, even though I have around five different file managers, including the 'default' Google one. Therefore, at least one of them should have worked.

I'm not sure if this issue is related to rooting, which I did using Magisk. I couldn't find anyone else online with this specific problem. I'm hoping that someone might be able to shed some light on what might be happening here or help me investigate it further.

Link to XDA thread: https://xdaforums.com/t/android-file-folder-activities-failing-on-kb2005.4636820/

Answer (score 0):

This exception occurs when there is no installed application that can be used as a [DocumentsProvider](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/DocumentsProvider).

Try installing a file explorer application that can be used as [DocumentsProvider](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/DocumentsProvider) (e.g. ES File explorer). File explorer applications that does not has the code bellow in their Manifest will not work:

```
<intent-filter>
   <action android:name="android.content.action.DOCUMENTS_PROVIDER" />
</intent-filter>
```

Assuming that the apps that crashed (Gmail) does not handle this case or catch the exception.

If the problem persist with ES File Explorer you can try if Signal or [ImagePicker](https://github.com/Dhaval2404/ImagePicker) works as they [catch this exception](https://github.com/Dhaval2404/ImagePicker/pull/12/commits/d0c62e2a08ac1e86a9d4153828a72a9a092b663a#diff-bf5de81807b1b0ec03a274ef62f61843f9cc14fafdadac5452d371c62a550f06) and use [Intent.ACTION_PICK](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#ACTION_PICK) or `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` (does not rely on `DocumentsProvider`) instead of `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`.

**References**

- https://code.briarproject.org/briar/briar/-/issues/2097
- [https://github.com/Dhaval2404/ImagePicker/pull/12/commits/d0c62e2a08ac1e86a9d4153828a72a9a092b663a](https://github.com/Dhaval2404/ImagePicker/pull/12/commits/d0c62e2a08ac1e86a9d4153828a72a9a092b663a#diff-bf5de81807b1b0ec03a274ef62f61843f9cc14fafdadac5452d371c62a550f06)

Comment: My file manager definitely has that in its manifest since it used to be able to open stuff. Either way, I have ES File Explorer installed. ImagePicker just has a popup saying something failed, and it doesn't crash. I've given up and reset my phone. I'll award the bounty, but this doesn't answer my question.